# Equation with divisors

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I solved one problem in our school math competition. And I think I find the answer in more general case. But I can't prove this. I need to solve the following problem to complete my proof.

1. Let S=$\{1 < d_1 < d_2 < ... < d_m < n \}$ is the set of all divisors of $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Here $m=\sigma_0(n)-2$.  ([$\sigma_m(x)$ - Divisor Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function). )
2. Let $k: 1 \leq k < [m/2] $ is an integer and $D_k=d_1 \cdot d_2 \cdot ... \cdot d_k$.
3. The equation $D_k^4=n^{4k-m}$ can be solved only if m=3, k=1.

The last 3) is my guess. I can't prove this. May be I'm wrong.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your question, is 3) the question you're trying to solve?

Comment: Yes! I try to solve this equation. My guess is, that it can't be solved in other cases (unless m=3,k=1).

Comment: If $n=2^{12}$, then $S=\{ 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024, 2048, 4096\}$ and m=11. So it is not a counterexample.

Comment: @Mike Oops, I didn't see that $m$ wasn't free! Let me think some more.

Comment: Maybe you should say *why* you guess that?

Comment: I just can't solve this equation in other cases. I do some little research on computer and I didn't find any solutions.

Comment: @Cocopuffs Sorry, It was my fault 2. I edit my question.

Comment: When you say "the equation can be solved", I guess you mean "this equation holds"? My point is, there doesn't seem to be any variable.

Comment: @tomasz May be i don't understand you. Are you asking me about prime problem which is leading us to this equation?

Comment: @tomasz It holds for $n = $ a prime power, since assuming $n = p^{m+1}$ and $D = p*...*p^k$ one gets a Diophantine equation: $8k^2 + 1$ must be a square. The only possibility for this is $k = 1$, which leads to $m = \frac{1}{2}(\sqrt{8k^2 + 1} + 4k - 1) = 3$. I don't know how to generalize this.

Comment: @Mike: No, I'm asking why do you think that should be true. It might give others ideas for a solution (or a counterexample).

Comment: @M Turgeon English is not my native. I mean folloming: There is not pair of any positive numbers (m,k) (unless (m=3,k=1) ) for which we can find such $n$ that $D_k^4=n^{4k-m}$.

Comment: @tomasz I've tryed to find any counterexample, as I say, even do some research on computer. I don't have any idea is it true or not. Thats why I am asking this from professionals.

Comment: @tomasz May be this can help. When I've tryed to solve my own idea about more general case I reduce that to the following: Let for S(n): $S_1=\{ d_1 < d_2 < ... < d_r \}$, $S_2=\{ d_{r+1} <  ... < d_{r+k} \}$, $m= r+k$. We need find such n, for which $d_1 \cdot ... \cdot  d_r = d_{r+1} \cdot ... \cdot  d_{r+k}$. And it is possible only if equation $D_k^4=n^{4k-m}$ is true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My comment above was incorrect; I relied on Wolfram Alpha which gave me a false answer. There are in fact infinitely many solutions, for example $k = 35$ which gives $m = 119$. Indeed, take $n = 2^{120}$, $m = 119$ and $k = 35$.  This gives a counterexample to 3, since $$D_k^4 = (2*...*2^{35})^4 = 2^{2*35*36} = 2^{2520} = 2^{120*(4*35 - 119)} = n^{4k - m}$$

Comment: and I believe that this is the smallest counterexample but would be interested if it isn't

Comment: I will leave the comment for reference. Everyone makes mistakes, especially me.

Comment: What a wonderful work! Thanks. I think I will try to find a similar counter-examples based on other primes then 2. My hypothesis was wrong :(. Think I should start another post with my prime problem.

Comment: I find the smallest: $n=2^{21}, \ m=20, \ k=6$. $D_6^4=(2\cdot 2^2\cdot....\cdot 2^6)^4=2^{2\cdot 6\cdot 7}=2^{84}$. $n^{4\cdot 6 - 20}=(2^{21})^4=2^{84}$.

Comment: @Mike This seems to work, yes

Comment: This is really the smallest counterexample: $n=320=2^6\cdot 5$. So $k=4, m=12$ and $D_4^4=2 \cdot 4 \cdot 5 \cdot 8=(2^6\cdot 5)^4$. And $n^{4k-m}=(2^6\cdot 5)^{16-12}=(2^6\cdot 5)^4$.

Comment: @Mike This is really good! I hope you were able to solve your more general problem, even without this lemma, by the way.

Comment: Thanks. It is just for fun. But very interesting for me.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [cocopuffs](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/32943/cocopuffs) it is clear now how to construct counterexamples.

Let $n = p^{a+1}$ here p is any prime number. It is easy to see in this case, that
$m=a$, $D_k^4=(p \cdot p^2 \cdot ... \cdot p^k)^4=p^{2k(k+1)}$ and $n^{4k-m}=(p^{a+1})^{4k-m}= p^{(m+1)(4k-m)}$. If $D_k^4=n^{4k-m}$ then 
$(m+1)(4k-m)=2k(k+1)$ and we have Diophantine equation: $2k - m + 4 k m- 2 k^2 - m^2 = 0$ with condition $k<m$ . First solution is $(k=1, m=3)$, second solution is $(k=6, m=20)$.

So $p=2, \ a=m=20, \ k=6, \ n=p^{21}$ is the smallest counterexamples.

By the way $k=35, m=119$ is the 3rd solution.

$$
k_n=\frac{(3 + 2\sqrt{2})^n-(3 - 2\sqrt{2} )^n}{4 \sqrt{2}},
$$

$$
m_n=\frac{1}{4} \left(\left(1+\sqrt{2}\right) \left(3+2 \sqrt{2}\right)^m+\left(1-\sqrt{2}\right)\left(3-2 \sqrt{2}\right)^m -2\right).
$$

$k_1=1, \ k_2=6, \ k_3=35, \ k_4=204$ and $m_1=3, \ m_2=20, \ m_3=119, \ m_4=696$.

$k_n=6k_{n-1} - k_{n-2}, \ \ m_n=6m_{n-1} - m_{n-2} + 2$.